# Check Out Password Protected File

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, excel-2010, password-protection

I have a file stored on SharePoint that is password protected. What I am trying to do is simply open the Excel workbook and enter the password so I can begin working (after running the macro to open it).

The code below is stored in my "launch" workbook and I am trying to use that to open the "data" workbook.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub TEST_OPEN()

Dim TestFile As String, wbActive As Workbook

    TestFile = "http://sharepointurl.com"
    Set wbActive = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TestFile, WriteResPassword:="passwordtext")

    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(TestFile) Then
        Excel.Workbooks.CheckOut TestFile
    End If

End Sub
```

The file opens with the password without issue but it fails to check out the Excel file.

Comment: won't the checkout be trying to check the file at the end of the link - not the file open on the desktop?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure what you mean. Like it's trying to check out a new instance of the TestFile and that's why it's failing. I'm not sure how to check out the open instance.

Comment: So, what is the name of the file as given at the top of its window?

Comment: @SolarMike the file name is "Dept Master 01012018.xlsx"

Comment: You should also consider your wbactive setting..

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure what you mean. Sorry I'm not that advanced with vba.

Comment: The line that starts with “Set wbActive...”

Comment: @SolarMike I know which line but I'm not sure what you mean by the statement I should consider it

Comment: In the if statement that follows, why not use wbactive instead of testfile , as testfile is a link, but wbactive should be the open file or you can reset wbactive to be the filenamexstarting  “Dept...”

Comment: @SolarMike so you're saying change "Workbooks.CanCheckOut(TestFile)" and  "Excel.Workbooks.CheckOut TestFile" to "Workbooks.CanCheckOut wbActive" and  "Excel.Workbooks.CheckOut wbActive" and it should work?

Comment: I can't test it as I don't have a file via a link like that and I would not rely on a link like that anyway (internet slow downs etc)... But it just seems to read wrong - you should be able to test it...

Comment: @SolarMike I'll test it tomorrow when I can

Comment: @SolarMike that did not end up working.